# Regex to split a sentence into simple English words

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence and I wish to extract all words from it. I define a word as [a-zA-Z] but also a word may contain an apostrophe. An apostrophe on its own is not a word. I am programming with Python3.

Input text:

```
Don't-thread 0 '' ' 'on \r\nme!
```

Should give:

```
Don't
thread
on 
me
```

with regard to regex splitting. Which I will then translate as follows using python:

```
Don't -> dont 
thread -> thread
on -> on
me -> me
```

More input:

```
   ''Kay', he said. 'What're you goin' to do?'
```

regex split and python translation should give:

```
   ''Kay' -> kay 
   he -> he
   said -> said
   'What're -> whatre
   you -> you
   goin' -> going
   to -> to
   do -> do
```

Here's what I currently use:

```
\b(\S+)\b
```

which obviously matches a lot more than what I'm interested in.

**UPDATE:**

Words can begin with an apostrophe. Such as "Get 'em!"

Comment: Sounds more like a split though... Have you tried anything so far? And what language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: We're here not to do entire work for you (even if it is simple). Please, show your approach

Comment: @ Alma Do Mundo Updated question

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what language you're having this regex... Also, which of the following characters are to be considered as a word here: `''Kay', he said. 'What're you goin' to do?'`?

Comment: @Jerry The following can be considered words: ''Kay'; he; said; 'What're; you; goin'; to; do; which I will then translate to: kay; he; said; whatre; you; goin; to; do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
[A-Za-z]+(?:'[A-Za-z]+)*
```

Which should work on most regex engines. Some of those groups can be shortened depending on the specifics of the regex engine, but that's a more general regex.

Makes sure the apostrophe is surrounded by letters.

EDIT: To allow initial apostrophes, you can simply add a `'?` at the beginning:

```
'?[A-Za-z]+(?:'[A-Za-z]+)*
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vZ5oS3)

Comment: Note that this won't accept words that start with an apostrophe. That may or may not be want the OP wants.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yup, that was intentional for the regex. Could've mistaken an apostrophe with a single quote otherwise, IMO.

Comment: @Jerry But words can begin with an apostrophe. Take for example "Get 'em!"

Comment: @Baz You have just added that condition...

Comment: @Jerry I just clarified that condition. Initially I said simply that an apostrophe on its own was not a word.

Comment: @Baz How does the last regex work?

Comment: @Jerry Seems to do what I want! Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your definition of a word is wrong, then. I'd probably define a word as

```
'?\p{L}+|p{L}+[p{L}']*
```

then.

Random note: Don't use `\b` unless you are absolutely sure you want its semantics (very rare) or it doesn't matter in your case. `\b` is closely linked to `\w` which is equally useless for language processing as it includes digits and the underscore.

Comment: `[\p{L}']*\p{L}[\p{L}']*` would be better IMO. There must be a letter, and there can be apostrophes or other letters to the left and right.

Comment: @Јοеу The definition is as follows: A word can start with letters or apostrophes, but if it starts with an apostrophe then it will need to be followed by at least on letter.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version:

Using [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) suggested regex and adding the escaped characters bit this might work for you

`#(?<!\\)[\p{L}']*\p{L}[\p{L}']*#`

---

First version:

This one works at least in PHP:

`#(?<!\\)(?:[IaA]|[A-Za-z]{2,})(?:'[A-Za-z]+)*#`

http://xrg.es/#iwgvz6

this bit: `(?<!\\)` is to ommit escaped characters